# clang error unknown argument '-fno-obj-arc' AFNetworking Xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, xcode, clang, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

So I tried to run my app on iPhone 7, and ASIHttp didn't work. After some search I saw that people are migrating to AFNetworking, so I decided to do the same. Here's what I did:

- Updated Xcode to version 5.1
- Followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking)
  (setup cocoapods, installed afnetworking, changed project)

and tried to run. The first build failed with this message:

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-fno-obj-arc' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

The only 2 reports I found about this are here and here

and they tell me to add some flag while doing the pod download:

```
ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future
```

Did that and tried again, to no avail. Now I can't even go back to the other project. Has anyone dealt with this problem so far? The option is in the command line, but I can't find anywhere to remove it. I don't think I should anyway.

Here's the command line, you can see the argument right after AFNetworking:

```
ProcessPCH /Users/cesarc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SPCMobile-aaaxjlqvwxhxfbhebqibusfjonip/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/SPCMobile-Prefix-bbhdqojfrkhfytgpvixlnglajmxy/SPCMobile-Prefix.pch.pch SPCMobile/SPCMobile-Prefix.pch normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/cesarc/Desktop/projetos/SPCMobile
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c-header -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wno-bool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DCOCOAPODS=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -mios-simulator-version-min=5.1 -I/Users/cesarc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SPCMobile-aaaxjlqvwxhxfbhebqibusfjonip/Build/Intermediates/SPCMobile.build/Release-iphonesimulator/SPCMobile.build/SPCMobile.hmap -I/Users/cesarc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SPCMobile-aaaxjlqvwxhxfbhebqibusfjonip/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/cesarc/Desktop/projetos/SPCMobile/Pods/Headers -I/Users/cesarc/Desktop/projetos/SPCMobile/Pods/Headers/AFNetworking -I/Users/cesarc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SPCMobile-aaaxjlqvwxhxfbhebqibusfjonip/Build/Intermediates/SPCMobile.build/Release-iphonesimulator/SPCMobile.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/cesarc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SPCMobile-aaaxjlqvwxhxfbhebqibusfjonip/Build/Intermediates/SPCMobile.build/Release-iphonesimulator/SPCMobile.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/cesarc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SPCMobile-aaaxjlqvwxhxfbhebqibusfjonip/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 -isystem /Users/cesarc/Desktop/projetos/SPCMobile/Pods/Headers -isystem /Users/cesarc/Desktop/projetos/SPCMobile/Pods/Headers/AFNetworking -fno-obj-arc --serialize-diagnostics /Users/cesarc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SPCMobile-aaaxjlqvwxhxfbhebqibusfjonip/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/SPCMobile-Prefix-bbhdqojfrkhfytgpvixlnglajmxy/SPCMobile-Prefix.pch.dia -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/cesarc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SPCMobile-aaaxjlqvwxhxfbhebqibusfjonip/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/SPCMobile-Prefix-bbhdqojfrkhfytgpvixlnglajmxy/SPCMobile-Prefix.pch.d -c /Users/cesarc/Desktop/projetos/SPCMobile/SPCMobile/SPCMobile-Prefix.pch -o /Users/cesarc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SPCMobile-aaaxjlqvwxhxfbhebqibusfjonip/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/SPCMobile-Prefix-bbhdqojfrkhfytgpvixlnglajmxy/SPCMobile-Prefix.pch.pch
```

Comment: It looks like you made a typo. It should be `-fno-objc-arc`.

Comment: Thought so too, but all this was automated. I can't find where to change and test it, AFNetworking won't show in the Build phases. I also have TBXML linked in this project, and the flag is obj instead of objc, and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the **Build Phases** section for the **Compile Sources**, you should have the *No Arc flag* (**-fno-objc-arc**) there, just make sure the spelling is correct.

1. [image: Build Phases:]
2. [image: Compile Sources]

Comment: Yep. My mistake was to add AFNetworking and updating Xcode at the same time. This issue had nothing to do with AFN, but with the change of rules with Xcode 5.1.